# What happens after a rocket is fired with velocity equal to or greater than escape velocity?

Tags: gravity, forces, escape-velocity

When a rocket is fired a speed greater than or equal to escape velocity, then it does not have any gravity effect of the earth.

So, suppose if a rocket is having that much energy which will only last for 1 sec.
Then it will move with 11.2km/s and it escapes from the earth.

My question is what happens after that?

Comment: It escapes! Just like the voyager probes it keeps heading out into deep space.

Comment: [Escape velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity). If you have exactly the escape velocity you will be on a [parabolic orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trajectory), and if you have any excess energy you will be on a [hyperbolic orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory). You escape to infinity, slowing down under gravity the whole time.

Comment: @kurtnelle if that is so then why rockets are taking much fuels

Comment: @kurtnelle - no, it doesn't escape the Solar System (you need the third escape velocity (42.1 km/s) for that. Java Programmer - the rocket will travel through the Solar System. We cannot say where it will be exactly without more data.

Comment: It takes a lot of fuel to launch a payload plus the fuel to launch a payload, plus the fuel for that, and that etc. The equation is exponential such that there is a practical limit to how much you can lift.

Comment: It hasn't escaped Sun yet!

Comment: This question should be transferred to Space Exploration space.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MichaelBrown i saw in Discovery science in which they have said that NASA has sent a spacecraft to move into outer solar system and it is run by slow degradation of some radioactive element. And the fuel is little sufficient till 2030.
My question why does it require fuel at all

Comment: The fuel there is a Radio Isotope which generates heat that runs a thermopile. This is how it provides electrical power to it's sensors. That fuel there is more like battery power.

Comment: Java Programmer: your question is unclear. Please [edit](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/71558/edit) it to add the point about RTGs (plutonium-238 - based generators) - it completely changes the question.

Comment: The problem is that we cannot accelerate a rocket to the escape velocity on the surface of the earth. That's why we need so much fuel: thrust is needed for a long period of time. The farther away from the surface of the earth, the weaker the gravitational force and thus the lower the escape velocity. So the rocket needs to keep burning fuel until it reaches a point where the escape velocity is equal to its current velocity. Then it can stop developing thrust. In the case of the extra-solar flight: the equipment on board needs the power to keep working.

Comment: @DeerHunter you are most welcome if you edit the question

Comment: Java Programmer - you are in the position to know better than me what exactly you want to ask.

Comment: @Wouter suppose if a rocket has sufficient fuel that can generate as much as thrust which can produce 11.2km/s for 1 sec then do you think it will keep on moving or it will stop or the speed decreases

Comment: Presuming it's outside the atmosphere (so it doesn't get slowed down by that and burn up) it will escape the Earth and slow down as it does so. Once it has escape velocity there is no need to keep pushing. Extra fuel is used for making course corrections. After going to Pluto the New Horizons probe will keep travelling outward and the extra fuel will be used to divert it to any suitable Kuiper belt objects which are near enough.

Comment: "if a rocket has sufficient fuel that can generate as much as thrust which can produce 11.2km/s for 1 sec" You are suffering from a confusion of physics. There is no amount of thrust which "Can produce 11.2 km/s for 1 sec." Either the thrust accelerates you to that speed - and then you keep that speed unless something slows you down - or you don't reach that speed at all.

Comment: As @medivh points out, your statement doesn't really make sense. You *can* (in theory) generate thrust in such a way that it takes 1 second of that thrust to get you to the escape velocity. Then, if the rocket is not impeded by any significant amount of particles (i.e. it has left the atmosphere - as Michael mentioned), the only decrease in speed will happen because of the everlasting but continuously decreasing gravitational influence of the earth. But by the very definition of the escape velocity you will never be brought to a full stop by this influence.

Comment: @Wouter i asked the question if it is possible theoretically or not

Comment: Well yes, but the sentence "generate thrust which can produce 11.2km/s for 1 sec" is not the same as "generate thrust in such a way that it takes 1 second of that thrust to get you to the escape velocity". The first sentence doesn't really make sense physically. I mean it *is* possible to generate thrust in such a way that you reach *and* maintain some constant speed for a duration of 1 second, if the thrust is variable and there is some force working against the motion. But I don't think that's what you wanted to know. (will continue below)

Comment: (continued) 
My other comment states what I think you wanted to know (2nd sentence: "You *can* ...") and tries to answer it. Did it not?

Comment: @javaprogrammer Are you familiar with the concept of [inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia)? It seems you have some basic (but common) misconceptions about motion. It doesn't take a force to continue motion. And neither velocity, force or energy are "used up" in any sense. It takes a force to *change* an object's state of motion, but once in motion it will continue forever in a straight line at constant speed unless another force stops it.

Comment: Your first sentence reflects a significant misunderstanding.  Even if the rocket exceeds escape velocity, there is still the same gravitational effect on the rocket.  It gets accelerated towards the center of the earth at 1g if you are near the surface.  The velocity is just high enough that it keeps going away from the earth.

Comment: @javaprogrammer, please see my answer addendum to address a question in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a comment by the OP.

> If you have gravitational pull even if your speed is greater than or
>   equal to escape velocity then what is the use of 11.2 km/s for a
>   rocket

javaprogrammer, to think that gravity somehow no longer affects the rocket after it attains escape velocity is to seriously misunderstand the nature of gravity.

The equation of motion that governs the rocket *does not depend on the speed of the rocket*.

For simplicity, consider the idealized case of just the Earth and the rocket.

The equation of motion tells us that the rocket, once the engine is shut down, *will always have an acceleration towards the Earth no matter how fast the rocket may be travelling away from the Earth*.

However, the equation of motion tells us something else, it tells us that, given a particular speed when the engine shuts off, there are three possible outcomes:

(1) the rocket will eventually slow, stop, and start travelling *towards* the Earth.  This is the case that the rocket does not have escape velocity when the engine stops.

(2) the rocket will slow with its speed approaching zero but never quite getting there.  This is the case that the rocket has exactly the escape velocity when the engine stops.

(3) the rocket will slow with its speed approaching some non-zero value but never quite getting there.  This is the case that the rocket has greater than escape velocity when the engine stops.

---

Addendum to address comment by OP:

> i saw in Discovery science in which they have said that NASA has sent
>   a spacecraft to move into outer solar system and it is run by slow
>   degradation of some radioactive element. And the fuel is little
>   sufficient till 2030. **My question why does it require fuel at all**

To produce electrical power to run the spacecraft systems.

Answer (score 5):

In simple terms, once the rocket has escape velocity it will keep flying away from the earth. And, once the rocket has that energy, even if only for 1 second, it will keep it and gradually convert that kinetic (movement) energy into potential energy (the energy it has by being higher in the earth's "gravitational potential well". The sum of kinetic and potential energy will always stay the same.

> When a rocket is fired a speed greater than or equal to escape
>   velocity then it does not have any gravity effect of the earth.

That is wrong. No matter how fast you go, or how far away you are, you always feel the gravitational pull of the earth. That means that you will slow down gradually. If you start with exactly escape velocity, then earth's gravity will reduce your speed to zero (relative to the earth) when you reach infinity, after an infinite time. If your initial speed is greater, then you will always have some speed, even at infinity

All the above assumes there is only the earth and the rocket. In reality, there are other bodies in the universe. At 11.2 km/s the rocket does not have enough velocity to escape from the solar system, so it will fly around the sun and may eventually even come back to the earth because of that. To escape from the sun itself, you need a speed of 617.5 km/s **relative to the sun**, not to the earth. However, as the earth already moves around the sun at a distance of 15,000,000 km, you don't need all of that speed to escape the sun from the earth. As Pulsar pointed out a mere 42 km/s will do.

Comment: The value 617.5 km/s is the escape velocity *on the surface of the Sun*. Instead, you need to use the escape velocity at the Earth-Sun distance, which is ~42 km/s. If you correct that, I'll give you a +1.

Comment: @hdhondt If you have gravitational pull even if your speed is greater than or equal to escape velocity then what is the use of 11.2 km/s for a rocket.Even if your speed is 1km/s then also you can move

Comment: @Pulsar yeah, I realised that too, shortly after posting the answer, but did not get around to correcting it.

Comment: @java I'm not sure what you're trying to say. At less than 11.2 km/s the earth will eventually pull you back. At a greater speed you will continue to move away from the earth, forever.

Comment: @hdhonhdt see when you throw a stone upwards,it does not have a speed of 11.2km/s but it goes upwards

Comment: @javaprogrammer But then it comes back down. If you throw it up with >11.2 km/s it *never* comes back down. Hence *escape* velocity.

Answer (score 2):

Only considering earth (no sun, no Milky Way galaxy, no [Andromeda galaxy](http://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/you_andromeda_and_largest_structure_universe-100856) - to each of which you are more strongly bound to than to Earth), and ignoring friction due to Earth's atmosphere, what would happen if you reach a velocity away from Earth slightly faster than the escape velocity: $v = v_{esc} + \delta v$?

Effectively you would be trading kinetic energy for potential energy, until you effectively escape earth's gravitational attraction and reach a final velocity that takes you ever farther away from Earth. Doing the math it follows that this final velocity equals $v_{final} = \sqrt{2 v_{esc} \delta v}$.

So if - after burning all your rocket fuel - you reach a speed of 11,201 m/s at a position where your local escape velocity is 11,200 m/s, you will start noticing a gradual drop in speed, until after some time you move away from earth at a speed of about 150 m/s. From that moment onward, you keep cruising at this speed.

Note that in the absence of friction you don't need any propulsion to maintain a given speed. You do need propulsion, however, if you wish to accelerate.

Comment: you stay in india? I got to know this from your profile. Me to stay in india.

Comment: my doubt is something else and i am getting some else still its useful to me so +1

Comment: @javeprog - yes, already a year in Bangalore. Time flies.